# How to carry out time lag analysis / cross correlation between wind and ocean wave data with python?

Tags: python, cross-correlation

I have hourly wind speed data and hourly surface wave height data and would like to see if these correlate and whether there is a time lag between the two. The data is currently in two separate panda data frames. I have tried using scipy.correlate and np.xcorr but they either return only zeros or the size of the data as the result. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
nsamples = wind.speed.size

wind.speed -= wind.speed.mean(); wind.speed /= wind.speed.std()
wave.HEIGHT -= wave.HEIGHT.mean(); wave.HEIGHT /= wave.HEIGHT.std()

xcorr = correlate(wind.speed, wave.HEIGHT)

dt = np.arange(1-nsamples, nsamples)

recovered_time_shift = xcorr.argmax()

print dt
print "Recovered time shift: %d" % (recovered_time_shift)
```

Many thanks,